# Can't output helper properties that are generated by my code in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to create a dropdown list which contains some province names. I also have another dropdown list which lists the cities of the province the user has chosen.
As you see in the helpers I have the list of provinces and I can access them and list them in the dropdown. Now for listing the cities, this is what I'm inteding to do... I have a helper named 'city' which is empty by default. In the events, I've created a change event (On provinceID)... Whenever the user changes the option of the dropdown this event runs... Using the switch, if the selected city is 'Tehran' for example, the city helper is filled by the cityHolder array. The problem is that it's not listed in the dropdown.
**This is part of the code**
In the main.js file:

```
Template.body.helpers({
/* #### LIST OF IRAN PROVINCES #### */
province: [
    {provinceName: 'Select the Province...', callingCode: ''},
    {provinceName: 'Tehran', callingCode: '021'},
    {provinceName: 'Yazd', callingCode: '352'},
    {provinceName: 'Gilan', callingCode: '131'}
],
city: [],
});

Template.body.events({
   'change #provinceID'(event, template)
{
    // ** Holds the value of the province dropdown **
    var provinceInputValue = document.getElementById('provinceID').value;
    // ** Checks which province has been selected **
    switch (provinceInputValue) {

        // #### 1. TEHRAN ####
        case 'Tehran':

            // ** List of Tehran cities **
            cityHolder = [
                {cityName: 'Tehran'},
                {cityName: 'Robat Karim'},
            ];
                for (var a = 0; a < cityHolder.length; a++) {
                Template.body.__helpers[" city"][a] = cityHolder[a];
            }
            break;
```

And this is main.html file:

```
<body>
<select id="provinceID">
    {{#each province}}
        {{> provinceTemplate}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
<select id="cityID">
    {{#each city}}
        {{> cityTemplate}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
</body>

<template name="provinceTemplate">
    <option value="{{provinceName}}" label="{{provinceName}}"></option>
</template>


<template name="cityTemplate">
    <option value="{{cityName}}" label="{{cityName}}"></option>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern for cascading menus is to set a `Session` variable when the primary menu changes and then (reactively) populate the dependent menu based on that.

```
Template.body.helpers({
  province(){
    return
      [
        {provinceName: 'Select the Province...', callingCode: ''},
        {provinceName: 'Tehran', callingCode: '021'},
        {provinceName: 'Yazd', callingCode: '352'},
        {provinceName: 'Gilan', callingCode: '131'}
      ];
  },
  city(){
    switch ( Session.get('provinceInputValue') ) {
      case 'Tehran':
        cityHolder = [
          {cityName: 'Tehran'},
          {cityName: 'Robat Karim'},
        ];
        break;
    }
    return cityHolder;
  }
});

Template.body.events({
  'change #provinceID'(event, template){
    let provinceElement = document.getElementById('provinceID');
    if ( provinceElement) Session.set('provinceInputValue',provinceElement.value);
  }
});
```

The key is that `Session` is *reactive* so that when the value of a session variable is updated the dependent code (in this case the function that returns your list of cities) is forced to update.

Comment: Then how the template declaration would change?? @MichelFloyd

Comment: " Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null " By changing the code... This is what I get... Why is that?

Comment: `var provinceInputValue = document.getElementById("provinceID").value;`@MichelFloyd<br> That's wired because when I run document.get... in the console it's working!

Comment: That's not in my code. When you run in the console the DOM is loaded but it's not when the code first runs. Look how I guard against that in the 3rd line from the bottom.

Comment: Yeap... It started working... I really appreciate your time @MichelFloyd <3